# Phonegap camera allowEdit: true still return the original photo

Tags: cordova

I use following code to capture an image and the success, but when I set the image in processImageUri function and display on the screen, it send up with the original image, before cropping. I am using Galaxy s4, Android 4.2

UPDATE

I checked my gallery, the saved image has been cropped, but why I got the original right after the cropping?

Any idea?

```
navigator.camera.getPicture($scope.processImageUri, $scope.onFail, {
    quality: 25,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit: true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    correctOrientation: true,
    targetWidth: 512,
    targetHeight: 512,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true
});
```

Comment: Which device are you using? allowEdit seems to only work on IOS

Comment: Updating the plugin to the latest fixed the problem :)

Comment: what was the version that you updated into because i have the latest plugin and the problem that you stated exist. i.e, original photo is being uploaded rather than the cropped image.